Why is Windows Hello for Business triggering in incognito mode?
I have a very interesting situation I can't explain. I have two users on two devices. Both users and devices are configured the same way. I literally checked everything and both users and devices are same in the scope of the configuration and logs.
However the first user (using the same browser as the second one) is prompted for WHFB method in incognito mode as an option to pass MS Entra ID MFA validation when logging to "office.com". The second user doesn't have this option at all (he must use regular MS Entra ID MFA options).
Microsoft is telling me here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/faq that WHFB can't be used in incognito mode. Well from my experience it can and I wonder what the hell is going on here.
Here are the options to pass MS Entra ID MFA in incognito mode with WHFB methods which has been set on the first device:

We are using Cloud Kerberos trust on hybrid-joined devices. Everything is configured properly. Every log and result and debug is okay.
I found out that the second user can be logged with WHFB in incognito mode of a browser when I choose the option "Sign-in options" on the portal "login.microsoftonline.com" instead of typing the user's UPN. When I type UPN I will go to our ADFS and then I have to use MS Entra ID MFA (WHFB is not as an option in this case). So IDK why the first user is asked for WHFB after passing ADFS and the second user is not asked for WHFB when passing ADFS. What is more important, is a fact that WHFB can be used in incognito mode of a browser in our case. IDK what the MS is talking about in the WHFB FAQ link I posted here.

I think I found answer:

Windows Hello for Business will be always triggered in incognito mode.
The first user had an option to use WHFB as a replacement of MS Entra ID MFA because the first user had FIDO2 HW key registered in his account. Without FIDO2 key as an authentication method, the first user has experienced the same login flow as the second user (without WHFB).
When we log-in in a way when we type UPN (email) to "login.microsoftonline.com" we are by default forwarded to our ADFS and then to MS Entra ID MFA. However, when we log-in using "Sign-in options" on "login.microsoftonline.com" then we can log in with WHFB and skip ADFS and MS Entra ID MFA competely (Passwordless sign-in).
What is important here is, that when we log in with WHFB using "Sign-in options" as I described here, on the next logins we are by default asked for WHFB. However in these future logins, when we choose that we don't want to use WHFB login and we choose to log-in with "Use a password" we are again redirected to ADFS and MS Entra ID MFA.  From here in all future logins we are asked for ADFS and MS Entra ID MFA again as a default login flow instead of WHFB.

